# Is it possible to obscure a portion of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given some vector space, V, and a region of that space, R, is it possible to obscure R? Said another way: can we choose a set of vectors in V so that linear combinations describe V-R but not R?

My thought is no, but if it is possible at all, I think it would depend on whether or not R contains the origin. This isn't for school or anything so no urgency. I tried searching a while, but don't really know how to limit the results to something relevant.

Answer (score 1):

In general: no. As you said, if $0 \in R$ then there can never be a subspace of $V$ that does not contain some element of $R$ since $0$ is linearly dependent with anything.

If you relax your restrictions some more and allow intersections at the origin (and assume $R$ to be a subspace of $V$) the thing you're asking for is precisely a complementary space of $R$. This has the important special case of so called orthogonal spaces: for any subspace $W$ of $V$ we can find its orthogonal space $W^\bot$ such that the "direct sum" of $W$ and $W^\bot$ is equal to $V$; in symbols
$$
V = W \oplus W^\bot.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I was making coffee a moment ago and realized that the vector space over the reals would work in the context of the vector space over the complex numbers. I'll look up complementary spaces tonight.